# Undefined Control Sequence due to TikZ-Tokens

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a question concerning this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{petri}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \node[place, tokens=2] (p) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the following two errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfutil@font@tiny ->\tiny 

l.8     \node[place, tokens=2] (p) {};

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfutil@font@tiny ->\tiny 

l.8     \node[place, tokens=2] (p) {};

?
```

If I set `tokens=3` I'll get accordingly the error three times, if I remove the tokens, everthing is fine. Can anyone, please, at lest tell me where to look for the error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because the `minimal` class doesn't define font sizes like `\tiny`. You should use `article` or some other "normal" class instead.

Errors like this are the reason why it is generally [not recommended](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/1098#1098) to use the `minimal` class for minimal working examples.